# Closed form of recursive sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, closed-form, recursive-algorithms

Suppose that I have sequences $\{\alpha_n,\beta_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and consider the sequence 
$(x_n)$ defined recursively by:

$$\begin{cases}x_0=a\\ x_1=b\\ x_{n+1}=\alpha_n \cdot x_n + \beta_n\cdot x_{n-1}\end{cases}$$

> **Is there a way to write the sequence $(x_n)$ in closed form in terms of the elements $a,b,(\alpha_n),(\beta_n)$?**

I supposed there should be a way to do this, but I have not been able to find it.

---

When $\alpha_n,\beta_n$ are constant, one can at least find a closed form in terms of powers of matrices by doing

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{n+1}\\ x_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & \beta\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_{n}\\ x_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}=\cdots =\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \beta\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^ n\begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\ x_0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \beta\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^ n\cdot \begin{pmatrix}b\\ a\end{pmatrix}$$

I guess one can do the same thing with the new problem obtaining:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{n+1}\\ x_n\end{bmatrix}=\left(\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_n & \beta_n\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\cdots \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_2 & \beta_2\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1 & \beta_1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\right)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}b\\ a\end{pmatrix}$$
Is there a better way to do it? what is the closed form?

Comment: http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/222/rec.pdf

Comment: @AspiringMat: OP is asking about the case in which $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ depend on $n$.

Comment: Wore: why should a sequence such as this one have a "nice" closed form, if nothing is known about the $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$?

Comment: @parsiad Sorry, I thought he meant constants.  Also OP, anything known about $\alpha _n$/$\beta _n$??

Comment: @AspiringMat Do you mean about the quotient? I was thinking in general, so nothing known about $\dfrac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n}$ either. Although, I would be interested in seeing how any assumption on the quotient might help.

Comment: @parsiad I am just asking if there is a nice closed form. May be the answer is not. I am really looking to a solution in terms of $a,b,\alpha_n,\beta_n$ in terms of sums, products, etc.

Comment: I am not aware of a method that works for any alpha or beta, however the reason I am asking is because some general cases of recurrences with non constant coefficients such as $f(n)x_n = cf(n-1)x_{n-1}+df(n-2)x_{n-2}+p(n)$ where c and d are constants and f,p are functions of n, can be reduced and have a general solution.

Comment: If it helps, this question occur to me when thinking about this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003709/is-there-anything-like-upper-tridiagonal-matrix-how-to-find-determinat-of-such/2003804#2003804

Comment: A method for certain alpha or beta may exist. However, for any at all, nothing can be said about the recurrence.

Comment: @Kaynex Why nothing can be said about the recurrence?

Comment: Well, we CAN say it's a linear recurrence, which allows us to find it's solutions by superposition. But, not much more than that.